# Really simple ajax + codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to learn the fundamentals of ajax but I can't really make it work. Here's what I'm trying.

File:create_comment.php (view)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
   $(function(){
       $("#comment").submit(function(){

         var name = $("#name").val();


         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/comment/create",
           data: "name="+name,
           dataType: 'json',

           success: function(result){    
                $('#write').html(result.returnValue);
           },
           error: function(xhr, status, error) { 
                alert('Error: '+ xhr.status+ ' - '+ error); },

         });

         return false;  

      });
   });
</script>

<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<h3>New Comment</h3>
<form id="comment" method="post">
<label>Name: </label><input type="text" id="name" name="name" /><br
<label>&nbsp;</label><input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<div id="write" ></div>
<!-- here is the script that will do the ajax. It is triggered when the form is submitted --></body></html>
```

File: comment.php (controller)

```
<?php

class Comment extends CI_Controller{

function  __construct() {

    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');
}

function index(){

    $this->load->view('create_comment');


}

function create(){

    if($_POST) {
           echo json_encode(array("returnValue"=>"This is returned from PHP")); 
    }
}


}
?>
```

What I'm always getting when I submit the for is: Error: 0 - OK
This means that I'm not even getting the 'success' function. If instead of echoing, I use 'return', then I'm going into the success function (but obviously I cannot output the results).

I know this must be the easiest question ever but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573243/php-reload-page-when-adding-forms-maybe-needs-ajax/7573935#7573935

Comment: I checked that. I'm still not sure how to fix it though.

Comment: I've checked your code and it works flawlessly for me, so this should be a configuration problem. What happens when you open `yourpage/index.php/comment/create/` as a page?

Comment: it could be because you have index.php in your url, what does your $config['base_url'] and $config['index_page'] variables in config.php look like also if you have one, what is does your .htaccess look like.

Comment: @Vlakarados That was right!! Please check my answer below!! Many thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Guys I found the solution.

I had set $config['compress_output'] = TRUE;

If I set it to FALSE everything works fine!!

Thank you all for your time!!

Comment: Glad you've got it working, it's interesting why it works this way

Answer (score -1):

[image]

To fix compression issue you have to enable it in php.ini without disable compress from codeigniter.